# Virtual Sitecore User Group - UK April 27

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

When (UTC): Tuesday, April 27, 2021 16:00

RSVP: https://scug.co.uk/events/2021/04/london-delete-sitecore-usergroup/

UK Sitecore User Group

The UK Sitecore User Group meets again on April 27. Come listen to Akshay Sura talk about the Sitecore Experience Edge and Daniel Ionita will run you through the .NET SDK for Sitecore's Content Hub.

Agenda (UTC):
16:00 – 16:05 Arrival and Opening 
16:05 – 17:20 Sessions 
17:20 – 17:20 Q & A  
17:20 - Closing

Presentations:

Kate Orlova & Anna Gevel: Two-way integration of Contacts between Sitecore xDB and MS Dynamics in real-time
Daniel Ionita: Expanding Sitecore Content Hub’s capabilities using the .NET SDK 
Akshay Sura: The Sitecore Experience Edge - Headless Content Delivery At-Scale

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 4 days